# What is length constraints of gmail api IDs?

Tags: gmail-api

I want to keep IDs of messages and other entities from [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) request results. And of course I want to have indexes on IDs columns in my storage.
Does somebody have an idea what is the max size of the IDs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Message/Thread IDs are a hexidecimal string of a 64-bit integer:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions#access_to_the_gmail_unique_message_id_x-gm-msgid

So should be string <= 16 characters long (2 hexideimcal characters for every byte * 8 bytes)